# Applying Shopping Cart Rule According To Shop and/or currency

Tags: cart, price, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping

I want to create a shopping cart rule which has a condition based on currency and/or store.
For example, 10% off only if the currency is USD.
Have searched thoroughly and can't find any info on how to attempt doing this or if there is an extension that may do it.
I am unable to do it according to category due to the way that the stores have been set up.
So, to ask as a more general question, is there a way to add conditions to a shopping cart rules that are based on chosen fields.

Answer (score 0):

So, I never did find a way to do this.
However, I found an extension that was very close to what I wanted to do and paid them to make the changes.
The extension is from Extendware.